# Realisation of the noncommutative torus as a universal $ C^{*} $-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

One of the most basic examples in noncommutative geometry is the so-called *noncommutative torus*, denoted here by $ \mathbb{T}_{\theta} $. As far as I know, there are several equivalent constructions of it:

1. as the $ C^{*} $-algebra of a foliation;
2. as a crossed-product $ C^{*} $-algebra;
3. as a universal $ C^{*} $-algebra.

I’m interested in the last construction. It is defined (here I follow M. Khalkhali’s book *Basic Noncommutative Geometry*) as a universal unital $ C^{*} $-algebra generated by two unitaries $ u $ and $ v $ with relation $ u v = \lambda v u $, where $ \lambda = e^{2 \pi i \theta} $. The author describes the concrete realisation of $ \mathbb{T}_{\theta} $ as follows. He defines two unitary operators $ U,V: {L^{2}}(\mathbb{S}^{1}) \to {L^{2}}(\mathbb{S}^{1}) $ by the formulas
$$
Uf(x) = e^{2 \pi i x} \cdot f(x), \quad Vf(x) = f(x + \theta)
$$
(where we think of $ \mathbb{S}^{1} $ as $ \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} $ to keep additive notation) and forms the $C^{*} $-algebra generated by these two unitaries. Then he then omits the proof that this $ C^{*} $-algebra is indeed universal.

I’ve asked one person who is more familiar than me with noncommutative geometry, and this person said that this is *folklore* and that he doesn’t know where I could find it in the literature. Hence, I would like to know if there is some standard procedure to handle such examples or if each example needs a particular method?

Comment: Ken Davidson's C*-algebra book has a proof of this fact

Comment: Thank You, I've checked in his book (You probably mean _$C^*$-algebras by example_) but I'm a bit confused because his construction is different: he uses $U$ and $V$ as above only for ensuring that there is at least one $C^*$-algebra with two unitaries satisfying such a relation. But he constructs universal $C^*$-algebra by taking all the irreducible pairs $(U_i,V_i)$ satisfying this relation. Then he formes $U=\bigoplus_{i}U_i, V=\bigoplus_{i}V_i$ so at the moment I'm not sure: noncommutative torus acts on the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i}L^2(S^1)_i$?

Comment: @truebaran  In Theorem VI.1.4 he shows that the universal C*-algebra generated by two unitaries $u,v$ that satisfy the relation $uvu^*v^*=\lambda$ is simple.  From this one deduces that whenever two unitaries satisfy $uvu^*v^*=\lambda$, they must generate a copy of $A_\theta$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to what I have seen in the literature so far, the standard procedure consists of two main steps:

- Prove the existence of a universal $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A_{\theta} $ generated by two unitaries $ u $ and $ v $ that satisfy
  $$
  u v = e^{2 \pi i \theta} v u.
  $$
  **Note:** We are assuming that $ \theta $ is irrational.
- Prove that $ A_{\theta} $ is simple, and conclude that the concrete realization given above is indeed universal.

---

To accomplish Step 1, there are several methods. I understand that you have read Davidson’s book, so let me describe an approach different from his that is more algebraic in nature.

1. Let $ \mathcal{P} $ denote the free associative unital $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra in four indeterminates, $ u $, $ u^{*} $, $ v $ and $ v^{*} $, where the identity element of $ \mathcal{P} $ is denoted by $ \mathbf{1} $.
2. Let $ \mathcal{I}_{\theta} $ denote the (not *a priori* proper) two-sided ideal
   $$
   \left\langle
   u u^{*} - \mathbf{1},
   u^{*} u - \mathbf{1},
   v v^{*} - \mathbf{1},
   v^{*} v - \mathbf{1},
   u v - e^{2 \pi i \theta} v u
   \right\rangle.
   $$
3. Form the quotient $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \mathcal{P} / \mathcal{I}_{\theta} $.
4. Let $ \dot{\mathbf{1}} $, $ \dot{u} $, $ \dot{u}^{*} $, $ \dot{v} $ and $ \dot{v}^{*} $ denote the images of $ \mathbf{1} $, $ u $, $ u^{*} $, $ v $ and $ v^{*} $ in $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ respectively.
5. Then the following monomials are distinct in $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ and define a Hamel basis for it:
   $$
   \dot{\mathbf{1}},                    \quad
   \dot{u}^{m} \dot{v}^{n},             \quad
   \dot{u}^{m} (\dot{v}^{*})^{n},       \quad
   (\dot{u}^{*})^{m} \dot{v}^{n},       \quad
   (\dot{u}^{*})^{m} (\dot{v}^{*})^{n}; \qquad
   (m,n) \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{2} \setminus \{ (0,0) \}.
   $$
   As such, $ \mathcal{I}_{\theta} $ is a proper ideal of $ \mathcal{P} $, and so $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ is a unital $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra.

> **Comment:** Wegge-Olsen claims that Point (5) is obvious, but I beg to differ as its validity depends on a non-trivial algebraic result called the **Diamond Lemma for Ring Theory**. Davidson appears to avoid all forms of algebraic machinery by resorting to the GNS Construction. However, as a staunch believer in the Principle of Conservation of Difficulty, I think that Davidson is simply transferring all technical issues from the Diamond Lemma to the GNS Construction, which, as most operator algebraists would agree, is a highly non-trivial result in the representation theory of $ C^{*} $-algebras.

6. Define a $ C^{*} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ to be a triple $ (A,s,t) $, where:

   - $ A $ is a unital $ C^{*} $-algebra.
   - $ s $ and $ t $ are unitary elements of $ A $ satisfying $ s t = e^{2 \pi i \theta} t s $.
7. Given a $ C^{*} $-representation $ (A,s,t) $ of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $, there exists a **unique** unital $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra homomorphism from $ \mathcal{P} $ to $ A $ defined by
   $$
   u     \mapsto s,     \quad
   u^{*} \mapsto s^{*}, \quad
   v     \mapsto t      \quad \text{and} \quad
   v^{*} \mapsto t^{*}.
   $$
   Then as the homomorphism kills $ \mathcal{I}_{\theta} $, we obtain a unital $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra homomorphism $ \pi_{A,s,t}: \mathcal{A}_{\theta} \to A $, once again **unique**, that satisfies:

   - $ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{u}) = s $ and $ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{u}^{*}) = s^{*} $.
   - $ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{v}) = t $ and $ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{v}^{*}) = t^{*} $.
   - $ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{u}) ~ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{v}) = e^{2 \pi i \theta} ~ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{v}) ~ {\pi_{A,s,t}}(\dot{u}) $.

> **Question:** Do $ C^{*} $-representations of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ exist?
>
> **Answer:** Yes! The concrete realization $ (\mathscr{B}({L^{2}}(\mathbb{T})),U,V) $ described by the OP is one. Amusingly, the very existence of this concrete realization shows that $ \mathcal{I}_{\theta} $ is a proper two-sided ideal of $ \mathcal{P} $, but I think we can safely say that this is not a demonstration of the fact from first principles.

8. Define a mapping $ \| \cdot \|_{0}: \mathcal{A}_{\theta} \to [0,\infty] $ by
   $$
   \| a \|_{0} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
   \sup
   (\{
   \| {\pi_{A,s,t}}(a) \|_{A} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \mid
   \text{$ (A,s,t) $ is a $ C^{*} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $}
   \})
   $$
   for each $ a \in \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $.
9. Proof sketch that $ \| \cdot \|_{0} $ is a $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra semi-norm:

   - Thanks to the existence of a $ C^{*} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $, we have
     $$
       \left\| \dot{\mathbf{1}} \right\|_{0}
     = \| \dot{u} \|_{0}
     = \| \dot{u}^{*} \|_{0}
     = \| \dot{v} \|_{0}
     = \| \dot{v}^{*} \|_{0}
     = 1.
     $$
   - As $ \dot{\mathbf{1}} $, $ \dot{u} $, $ \dot{u}^{*} $, $ \dot{v} $ and $ \dot{v}^{*} $ generate $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $, it follows that $ \| a \|_{0} < \infty $ for each $ a \in \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $.
   - Knowing now that $ \| \cdot \|_{0}: \mathcal{A}_{\theta} \to [0,\infty) $, it is easily shown to satisfy the axioms of a $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra semi-norm.
10. Notice that $ \| \cdot \|_{0} $ also satisfies the $ C^{*} $-identity.
11. Let $ \mathcal{N} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \{ a \in \mathcal{A}_{\theta} \mid \| a \|_{0} = 0 \} $. Then $ \mathcal{N} $ is a $ \mathbb{C} $-subalgebra of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $.
12. Form the quotient $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} / \mathcal{N} $ to get a pre-$ C^{*} $-algebra, denoting the quotient norm by $ \| \cdot \| $.
13. Complete $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} / \mathcal{N} $ with respect to $ \| \cdot \| $ to obtain the irrational rotation $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A_{\theta} $.
14. Clearly, $ A_{\theta} $ is unital and is generated by the pair $ ([\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}) $ of unitary elements. Furthermore,
    $$
      [\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}} [\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}
    = e^{2 \pi i \theta} [\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}} [\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}}.
    $$

This completes the construction.

---

> **Claim:** $ (A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}) $ is a universal $ C^{*} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $.

*Proof of Claim*

Let $ (A,s,t) $ be a $ C^{*} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $. Then by the definition of $ \| \cdot \|_{0} $,
$$
\forall a \in \mathcal{A}_{\theta}: \quad
\| {\pi_{A,s,t}}(a) \|_{A} \leq \| a \|_{0} = \| [a]_{\mathcal{N}} \|.
$$
We thus have a **unique** unital $ * $-homomorphism $ \pi_{A,s,t}^{\mathcal{N}}: \mathcal{A}_{\theta} / \mathcal{N} \to A $ satisfying
$$
{\pi_{A,s,t}^{\mathcal{N}}}([\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}}) = s \quad \text{and} \quad
{\pi_{A,s,t}^{\mathcal{N}}}([\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}) = t,
$$
and we can extend this, using continuity, to a **unique** unital $ * $-homomorphism $ \Pi_{A,s,t}: A_{\theta} \to A $. In other words, $ \Pi_{A,s,t} $ is the **only** unital $ * $-homomorphism from $ A_{\theta} $ to $ A $ that maps $ [\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ to $ s $ and $ [\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ to $ t $.

Now, suppose that there is another unital $ C^{*} $-algebra $ B $ generated by two unitaries $ u' $ and $ v' $ satisfying
$$
u' v' = e^{2 \pi i \theta} v' u'
$$
such that for any $ C^{*} $-representation $ (A,s,t) $, there exists a **unique** $ * $-homomorphism $ \Phi_{A,s,t}: B \to A $ that maps $ u' $ to $ s $ and $ v' $ to $ t $.

The following statements are then true:

- $ \Pi_{B,u',v'}: A_{\theta} \to B $ is the **unique** $ * $-homomorphism that maps $ [\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ to $ u' $ and $ [\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ to $ v' $.
- $ \Phi_{A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}}: B \to A_{\theta} $ is the **unique** $ * $-homomorphism that maps $ u' $ to $ [\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ and $ v' $ to $ [\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}} $.
- $ \Phi_{A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}} \circ \Pi_{B,u',v'}: A_{\theta} \to A_{\theta} $ equals $ \text{id}_{A_{\theta}} $ on a dense subset of $ A_{\theta} $.
- $ \Pi_{B,u',v'} \circ \Phi_{A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}}: B \to B $ equals $ \text{id}_{B} $ on a dense subset of $ B $.

Therefore, $ \Phi_{A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}} \circ \Pi_{B,u',v'} = \text{id}_{A_{\theta}} $ and $ \Pi_{B,u',v'} \circ \Phi_{A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}} = \text{id}_{B} $, and so $ A_{\theta} $ is $ * $-isomorphic to $ B $ via the **unique** $ * $-isomorphism that sends $ [\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ to $ u' $ and $ [\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}} $ to $ v' $.

This concludes the proof that $ (A_{\theta},[\dot{u}]_{\mathcal{N}},[\dot{v}]_{\mathcal{N}}) $ is indeed a universal $ C^{*} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $. $ \quad \blacksquare $

---

The proof that $ \Pi_{\mathscr{B}({L^{2}}(\mathbb{T})),U,V}: A_{\theta} \to {C^{*}}(U,V) $ is a $ * $-isomorphism follows from the non-trivial fact that $ A_{\theta} $ is a simple $ C^{*} $-algebra (i.e., it has no non-trivial closed proper two-sided ideals). The main idea behind the proof is to use the so-called **trace function** on $ A_{\theta} $.

This trace function does wonders for us. Firstly, it shows that $ A_{\theta} $ contains a non-trivial projection element. Secondly, it shows that $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ is faithfully represented as a $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra in $ A_{\theta} $, i.e., $ \mathcal{N} = \{ 0_{\mathcal{A}_{\theta}} \} $. Observe that in defining the $ C^{*} $-semi-norm $ \| \cdot \|_{0} $, there was no guarantee that each non-zero element of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ would not be sent by $ \| \cdot \|_{0} $ to $ 0 $. Playing around with the trace function shows that this is indeed the case.

Comment: +1 I'm very late to the party, but this is an excellent answer.

Comment: @Branimir: Thanks for the compliment!

Comment: If one were to construct a rational commutative torus, what would one do differently?

Comment: Thanks for the previous answer. Another question: Doesn't it lead to size issues considering the supremum taken over all $C^*$-representations?

Comment: @Svinepels: Hi. I have deleted my answer to your previous question in order to give a more detailed explanation here. A rational non-commutative torus $ A_{\theta} $, where $ \theta \in \Bbb{Q} $, is constructed in exactly the same manner as in my post, but it is not a simple $ C^{*} $-algebra. In fact, we have $ \operatorname{Prim}(A_{\theta}) \cong \Bbb{T}^{2} $ as topological spaces.

Comment: @Svinepels: Regarding your latest question, there is no set-theoretical issue. If $ \varphi(x) $ is a formula in the first-order language of set theory, and if $ X $ is a set, then according to the Axiom Schema of Specification,
$$
\{ x \in X \mid \varphi(x) \}
$$
is a set. In Step 8 of my post, $ X = \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0} $, and $ \varphi(x) $ reads “there exist a $ C^{\ast} $-algebra $ A $ and elements $ s,t $ of $ A $ such that $ (A,s,t) $ is a $ C^{\ast} $-representation of $ \mathcal{A}_{\theta} $ and $ x = \| {\pi_{A,s,t}}(a) \|_{A} $”.

Comment: @truebaran: this seems like a very complete answer to your question, why don't you accept it?

Answer (score 6):

For a $C^\ast$-algebraic approach to noncommutative two dimensional torus you may want to look at the Marc Rieffel paper [$C^\ast$-algebras associated with irrational rotations](http://msp.org/pjm/1981/93-2/pjm-v93-n2-p12-s.pdf). For more detailed study of noncommutative torus including higher dimensions I suggest the book [Elements of noncommutative geometry](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=2yJIwWbh1isC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=elements%20of%20noncommutative%20geometry&ots=ey0SdolYVN&sig=DrRvIlx5bBlQ_sowlILRIFgNGgE).

About your question: Marc Rieffel has a deformation quantization theory based on operator algebras whose one of the examples is noncommutative torus, see his paper [Deformation quantization for actions of $R^d$](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=B0UsGtlXyAcC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=marc%20rieffel%20deformation%20quantization&ots=LZNF25Lp07&sig=b9iD4zRffGHnK7OeUO8ehYeZ_p4). Of course noncommutative torus is a very special case and admits many different interpretations as a noncommutative space, as you said!